# Fast way to find a matrix with only $0$ and $1$ as entries full-rank or not?

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a huge number of small Zero-One Matrices($4\times 4$, $5\times5$,$6\times6$) and I want to determine whether they are full-rank or not one by one.

Gaussian elimination is a option, I want to know is there any faster way since only $1$s and $0$s in the matrices.

I wrote a test program by myself:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    GMatrixU8 mat;                        
    int i=1000*1000;
    while(--i>=0){                         
        mat.Make_random(6,6,1);         
        //1000,000 matrices is randomly generated in the loop
        Is_full(mat);
        //Is_full() function utilize the gaussian elimination to judge 
        //whether this matrix is full-rank or not
    }   
return 1;
}
```

and this program runs in 5 seconds in my computer. I think this is can be optimized by a better algorithm.

Comment: What software are you using that is not fast enough as is?

Comment: C/C++，I want to find a better algorithm, not a better language.

Comment: Yes, C/C++ _is_ a language and it is used to create software. I asked because the software I use (which is written in fortran if you are interested) gets the rank of a matrix from its SVD. Perhaps if I knew what software you are using, we could compare and see if using the SVD might help you out.

Comment: How many of these matrices do you have? The python command ranks = [numpy.linalg.matrix_rank(mtrx) for mtrx in mtrxList] was able to compute the ranks of $100,000$ $6 \times 6$ zero-one matrices in about $7$ seconds.  That's probably not fast enough for your application, but I'm curious to know what kind of runtime you're seeing so far.

Comment: @littleO Thanks for your attention, I compute the ranks of $1000,000$ $6\times 6$ zero-one matrices in about 4 seconds, but I think this is can be optimized by a better algorithm.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Thanks for your anttention, I didn't use other softwares to compute the ranks of these matrices, I wrote the program by my self.

Comment: Are you using single/double precision numbers in your code? I ask because I think the rule of thumb is ~30-50 clock cycles for floating point summuation and something like 5 for ints. (I could be way off on the numbers; it's been a while.)

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 the entries are presented by ints.

Comment: Are using logic (xor,or,and) or arithmetic (+,-,*)? Is parallelizing your algorithm an option so that it will work on more than one matrix at a time? If so, don't all CPU nowadays have at least 256-bit vector units? That combined with the logical operations might let you compute the rank for several at a time.

Comment: You do know much! Although you didn't give me suggestions to the algorthm, I will make some improvement according to your advise. I will change arithmetic operations to logic opertions, and maybe apply some SIMDs.

Comment: Also, are you working in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Working in Z2 .

Comment: This is like a heresy, but couldn't you just compute the determinant of that matrix and compare it to 0? It will be again an integer and you can exploit zeros in Laplace expansion. Any other scheme like LU or SVD cannot avoid conversion to floating point numbers.

Comment: @PavelJiranek Since he is working in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, could the determinant be reduced to a series of bit-wise logic operations? Something where each single bit position is a sort of accumulator for an individual matrix? For instance, if using 64-bit integers, we can add 64 elements together with a single OR. If we have a 4x4 matrix, could we use 16 variables and a series of ANDs and ORs to compute all 64 determinants in parallel? Does that make sense?

Comment: I never worked with anything else than $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ matrices, but I guess that some meaningful optimization w.r.t. to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ matrices could be possible. But still it somewhat depends on what the "user" wants.